# Cross database search criteria object

Tags: java, hibernate, cross-database

In php Codeigniter you can write:

```
$this->db->select('username')->from->('users')->where('id',5);
```

Do you know any good lib for java/hibernate that function the same?
Thanks

Comment: This is probably the most basic thing that hibernate does (essentially a simple select query on an id). What am I missing? What does "cross-database" mean in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about some kind of typed queries than have a look at [Hibernate Criteria API](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html).

When you like it even more typed, than hava a look at the typesave queries provided by the JPA 2.0 functionality of Hibernate (@see http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-typesafejpa/)